# angular-ui-tinymce bindings не работают

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

Использую ui-tinymce для отображения автосгенерированного отчёта (чтобы пользователь мог поправить).

```
<form method="post"><textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinyMceContent"></textarea></form>
```

Разметку прописываю в переменную `tinyMceContent` (не знаю другого способа), вот часть для примера:

```
this.$scope.tinyMceContent =  `
    <h1>
        {{test.type}} TEST RESULTS
    </h1> `
```

В итоге она так и рендерится с текстом "{{test.type}} TEST RESULTS", то есть привязка не срабатывает. Насколько я понимаю, ui-tinymce как раз и создана чтобы решить проблемы совместимости с ангуларом, в документации написано, что если возникли ошибки нужно сделать ререндеринг с помощью `this.$scope.$broadcast('$tinymce:refresh');`. Я так и делаю в `$onInit`, но это тоже не помогает.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как заставить биндинги работать и можно ли?

Comment: А апостроф тоже рендерится?

Comment: @RomanC, нет, и h1 тоже, на выходе есть только текст:
{{test.type}} TEST RESULTS